# Vconcat of separate FacetCharts do not have aligned grids - how to get them to align?

Tags: python, plot, data-science, altair, vega

I want to plot a grid of plots, with the faceted row and columns determined by different variables. I would like to use a single FacetChart for this, but because the rows contain different variables on the x axis, the order of magnitude of those variables is different, and I want the x-axis scale shared separately in each row, I have no choice but to create two separate FacetCharts and to VConcat them together. When I do this, the spacing of the grids is different so plots do not align, and the result is visually unpleasant. What settings can I use to ensure the grids align?

I have two data frames
[image: Dataframes used].

I plot the data with this code

```
(
    alt.Chart(vert_heat_flux_data_1hr).mark_line().encode(
        alt.X('value:Q', sort='y', title="w'tc'"),
        alt.Y('height:Q', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
        alt.Color('day:N')
    ).properties(
        width=73,
        height = 100
    ).facet(
        column='hour:O',
        spacing=7
    ) & 
    alt.Chart(vert_moisture_flux_data_1hr).mark_line().encode(
        alt.X('value:Q', sort='y', title="w'q'"),
        alt.Y('height:Q', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
        alt.Color('day:N')
    ).properties(
        width=73,
        height = 100
    ).facet(
        column='hour:O',
        spacing=7
    )
)
```

which results in this plot.
[image: The resulting plot]

Why do the grids not align? It seems that after specifying plot width and height and facet spacing that the grids would align.

Comment: It might be because of the extra decimal in the bottom row. You could try formatting the x-axis (or just multiplying it by 10) and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: That did not help, but adding the following to each `alt.X` encoding, respectively, did help?


`scale=alt.Scale(domain=[-0.1, 0.3])`


`scale=alt.Scale(domain=[-0.005, 0.025])`